# How to count number of objects stored in a *.ser file

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to read all the objects stored in a *.ser file and store them in a array of objects. How can I get the number of objects stored in that file(So that I can declare the array to be `number_of_objects` long)?

I've checked the API and was unable to find a Desirable function.

-edit-
A Part of the code:

```
Ser[] objTest2 = new Ser[number_of_objects];
for(int i=0; i<=number_of_objects, i++) {
    objTest2[i] = (Ser)testOS2.readObject();
    objTest2[i].printIt(); 
}
```

Comment: A file which stores serialized objects(I don't know the proper terminology, it's my first week with java).

Comment: Ok, well what you want for sure is the `List` interface.  The specific implementation will be `ArrayList`.

Comment: since you don't know how any object are in the file, that code will not work.  You need some while loop to continue reading while there are objects left in the stream.  And, as you read, continue to add each new object to the List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to look at is the [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class.

It is basically a dynamically growing Array.

You can add items to it like so:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(someObject);
list.add(anotherBoject);
```

The list will grow as you add new items to it.  So you don't have to know the size ahead of time.

If you need to get an array out if the List at the end you can use the `toArray()` method of List.

```
Object[] arr = list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]);
```

**Edit:**
Here is a general implementation of what you need:

```
List<Ser> objTest2 = new ArrayList<Ser>();
while (testOS2.available > 0) {
    Ser toAdd = ((Ser)testOS2.readObject());
    toAdd.printIt(); 
    objTest2.add(toAdd);
}
```

*I don't think `available()` is a reliable test for whether or not there are more bytes to read.

Comment: I don't think that I require that here. Here's a part of the code. -edited- code added in main post.

Comment: @MoonStruckHorros You do require that (but do add generics). You need to deserialise the stream to find the number of (top-level) objects (unless you were to store that information somewhere ahead). / In general, arrays of references should be avoided - use `List` instead.

Comment: `available()` is not in any way a test for end of file. See the Javadoc. The correct way to detect that here is to catch `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

Year's later this post is still relevant. I was looking for a way to loop through a .ser file while de-serializing each  file, and to some extent, Rohit Singh's post helped. This is my version of the same though:

```
ArrayList<Profile> availableProfiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("profiles.ser");
        ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream);

        Object profileObject = null;
        while((profileObject = os.readObject()) != null) {
            Profile castObject = (Profile) profileObject;
            availableProfiles.add(castObject);
        }
        os.close();
    }  catch(Exception ex) {
        if(ex instanceof EOFException) {
            out.println("End of file reached!");
            out.println("Total profiles found is: " + availableProfiles.size());
        } else if(ex instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            out.println("File not found! \n Answer the following to create your profile");
            createProfile();
        }
    }
```

The most important part is the **position of the while-loop**. In my version, that loop does not create a new FileInputStream or ObjectInputStream like Singh's does. That will make the ObjectInputStream read the .ser file afresh each time those two are created, and as a result, you only add() one Profile object to the ArrayList- the first one to be serialized- each time the loop restarts.
Instead, we only loop the with the readObject() method until it produces a null signifying no other object was found in the file, and it triggers the EOFException.

Answer (score -1):

Just keep reading objects until you get EOFException. That's what it's for. And use a `List` instead of an array so you don't need the count in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
  while(true)
 {

      try
      {
      Employee e=(Employee) ois.readObject();
      System.out.println("successfully deserialized.........showing details of object.");
      e.display();
      }

      catch(Exception e)
      {
          if(e instanceof java.io.EOFException)
          {
          System.out.println("All objects read and displayed");
          break;
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Some Exception Occured.");
              e.printStackTrace();

          }
        }
 }
```

Comment: `EOFException` should be caught separately, not detected like this. Mere code is not an answer: you have to explain.